# Why does only the built-in UIColors work here?

Tags: swift, scenekit, uicolor, scnnode

Having failed miserably at further attempts to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54934109/scnaction-to-change-color-of-node-works-once-then-never-again) on my own, I'm trying something I thought would work for certain:

```
func switchColor(data:UInt32){
        switch data {
        case 1..<200:
            backgroundGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents =
                UIColor(red: CGFloat(242), green: CGFloat(90), blue: CGFloat(90), alpha: 1.0)
        case 200..<400:
            backgroundGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents =
                UIColor(red: CGFloat(252), green: CGFloat(162), blue: CGFloat(115), alpha: 1.0)
        case 400..<600:
            backgroundGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents =
                UIColor(red: CGFloat(244), green: CGFloat(235), blue: CGFloat(99), alpha: 1.0)
        case 600..<800:
            backgroundGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents =
                UIColor(red: CGFloat(110), green: CGFloat(195), blue: CGFloat(175), alpha: 1.0)
        case 800..<1000:
            backgroundGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents =
                UIColor(red: CGFloat(91), green: CGFloat(118), blue: CGFloat(211), alpha: 1.0)
        default:
            backgroundGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
        }
    }
```

All the non-default cases turns the node white.
The default case does turn it green - and within each case, statements like UIColor.red, UIColor.blue work fine as well.

So why the heck doesn't the above statements work?

Hope you can help, I'm completely at a loss here :(

Edit: Thanks for the swift and not least correct answers! All accepted and upvoted, but I'm too much of a newbie for it to display. Thanks! :)

Comment: Just like the other person commented on your previous questions, the values you must provide in the initialiser are values from 0...1, just like the alpha value, not 0...255. All of the cases in the code you provided will create a white color, because you are essentially initialising the color with max RGB values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
func switchColor(data: UInt32) {
    guard let contents = backgroundGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents else {
        fatalError("First material is nil") // If this really can be empty, just replace this with return
    }

    switch data {
    case 1..<200:
        contents = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 90/255, blue: 90/255, alpha: 1)
    case 200..<400:
        contents = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 162/255, blue: 115/255, alpha: 1)
    case 400..<600:
        contents = UIColor(red: 244/255, green: 235/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1)
    case 600..<800:
        contents = UIColor(red: 110/255, green: 195/255, blue: 175/255, alpha: 1)
    case 800..<1000:
        contents = UIColor(red: 91/255, green: 118/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1)
    default:
        contents = .green
    }
}
```

The maximum value of a color is 1.0, not 255. Therefore you need to divide the values.

Comment: Which is why the answerer divides the values by 255

Comment: If you are working on a value between 0 and 255 you need to divide it by 255 to result in a floating number from 0...1

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct them like

```
UIColor(red:242.0/255.0, green:90.0/255.0, blue:90.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

you can find the init in [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init)

> red/blue/green values below 0.0 are interpreted as 0.0, and values above 1.0 are interpreted as 1.0.

Another note also there is a difference between

```
90/255   // wrong
```

and

```
90.0/255.0  // right
```

the latter is the correct one as the former will truncate the floating part as it's an integer division

Comment: Your note is wrong. Because the parameters are CGFloats, Swift will infer 90/255 to be the division of two CGFloats and give the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the red, green, blue and alfa values are Float between 0.0 to 1.0 respectively. Also, a value below 0.0 is treated as 0.0 and value above 1.0 is treated as 1.0.
So you must construct the UIColor as this

```
UIColor(red: 91/255, green: 118/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1)
```